# How can I use a formula with an IF function?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, last-modified

I'm wanting to check for blank cells, and when the cell is not blank, output a formula. However, I am getting errors and I believe you're not allowed to use formulas within an IF function, are you guys able to help me out?

```
=IF(A1="","",=lastModified(A1))
```

If the cell is not empty, this formula will return the date the cell was last modified. I do not want the date updated if the cell is blank.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `lastModified` a macro function you defined?

Comment: Yes, it is. lastModifed = Now()

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you saying you want to put the result of `lastmodified(A1)` into cell A1? Or are you wanting to give A1 the value `=lastmodified()` if it's empty? Or something else entirely? (Please don't answer in a comment, but [edit] your question itself to make it clear what you're trying to accomplish.)

Comment: It's unclear what I am asking? All I'm asking was how to use a formula within an IF function. That is all, but don't worry, someone's already answered my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the formula, just remove the equals sign. It will call when the FALSE condition triggers in your IF statement.

```
=IF(A1="","",lastModified(A1))
```

Comment: Don't understand how this go a downvote, but it worked haha. Thanks for that, such an easy mistake.